# How to achieve overstriking text effect with css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, typography

I made a little landing page and the client wants: "The text, Sourcing & Trading, CCTV security. Want to use overstriking.
Then all will be OK." I googled what overstriking is and I have to admit I'm a little hazy on the concept and not sure how to implement it with CSS at.

The code I tried is in the snippet bellow. Thanks in advance.

```css
footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height:100px;
  line-height: 10px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  padding-top:10px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.main-buttons {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0  auto;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
span{
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.main-container {
  background-image: url('http://wenshin.ltd/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/logisticsworldmap-1024x586.png');
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.middle{
  top: 50%;
}
.btn-lg {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px #888888;
}
h1 {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #888888;
}
.logo {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body class="main-container">
  <div class="container middle">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center ">
        <div class="intro"> <br> <br>  <br> <br>
          <img src="http://wenshin.ltd/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/WS-01.png" class="img-fluid logo" alt="Logo"> <br> <br>
          <h1 class="">WELCOME TO WENSHIN <br> INDUSTRIAL CO LIMITED</h1>
          <p>
            <a href="http://www.wenshin.ltd/index.php">
                <button class=" main-buttons btn btn-light btn-lg mt-3">Sourcing & Trading</button> 
            </a>
            </p>
            <p>
            <a  href="http://www.cctvcamerahd.com/">
                <button class="main-buttons btn btn-light btn-lg mt-3">CCTV Security</button>
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <span class="text-center"><p><strong>Choose your language:</strong></p></span>
        <span class="text-center"><p><span>English</span>   <span>繁體中文</span>   <span>Español</span>    <span>Português</span>  <span>Deutsch</span>    <span>Français</span>   <span>Italiano</span>   <span>Pусский</span>    <span>한국어</span>    <span>日本語</span>    <span>Nederlands</span> <span>غة العربية 
          </span>   <span>Indonesian</span>
          </p></span>
      </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I used:

```
text-decoration: line-through;
```

And I wondered if that's it or is there something alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would ask my client what he means by that.
Most people mean a strikethrough by saying overstrike.

You would just have to add this to your css for these buttons.

```
text-decoration: line-through;
```

As for the overstriking, it is an old technique used in the time of typewriters to write letters that where not on the "Keyboard". It doesn't really make sense anymore.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, yea that's what I did basically, it doesn't look too good in my opinion, but client is the one who's paying and if he likes it what do I care :D

Comment: @MirzaSisic Haha exactly it's his choice at the end! :)

Answer (score 1):

This just in....  I managed to answer my own question.

Since it turns out that (at least for my device) the inline «`style`» attribute accepts «`/**/`» comments like its stylesheet cousin, I thought it would be helpful to "good doctor" the code to make it easier to follow:

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">An element with &#xab;position: relative;&#xbb;
  [such as
  <span style="/*Block setup*/display: inline-block; position: relative;
               /*Adjust to match print baseline*/vertical-align: -7.5%;
               /*Block width*/width: 6.5em;">
     <span style="/*Element Name*/position: absolute;
                    left: 0em;">C&#xE6;sium (</span>
     <span style="/*Isotope weight*/font-size: 60%; vertical-align: 55%;
                    position: relative;/**/ left: 6.0em;">133</span>
     <span style="/*Atomic number*/font-size: 60%; vertical-align: -25%;
                    position: relative;/**/ left: 4.6em;">55</span>
     <span style="/*Element Symbol*/position: relative;
                    left: 2.5em;">Cs)]</span>
 </span> is positioned relative to its normal position:</p>`
```

The user may need to jiggle about the «`width`» and «`left`» properties to smooth out the spacing for their system (as well as prune the comments if storage space us at a premium).

Answer (score 1):

Note that a line above chacters is called overline, not overstrike, and has the HTML-attribute:

```
text-decoration: overline;
```